# how to open Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, team-explorer

I have `VS2008 Professional Edition with SP1` installed on my machine. Currently we use Visual Source Safe for version controller but we want to change it with `Team Foundation Server 2010/2012`. So i need to connect TFS with VS2008. 

I read some post on the net and they say there is Team Explorer on `Tools/Connect to Team Foundation Server` to connect to TFS. This should already be installed with VS2008 SP1 but i dont see anything about Team Explorer in my VS2008 menus.
How can i open Team Explorer in my VS2008 to connect to TFS that we are planning to install? Or how can i verify that Team Explerer is installed on my machine?

Comment: You need to install the TFS stuff for VS. It is not included by default in VS2008.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First check if Team Explorer is installed:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Open Menu Help
3. Open "About Microsoft Visual Studio"
4. Check for entry like Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer Version 9.0.30729.4413
5. If not, install Team Explorer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16338 and (re-)install VS SP1 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986

If this is installed, check if you selected TFS as Version Control system:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Open Menu Tools
3. Open "Options ..."
4. Go to "Source Control" -> "Plug-In selection"
5. Choose Team Foundation Server

Now you should be able to use Team Explorer. To do this:

1. Open Menu View
2. Choose "Team Explorer"
3. Connect to you TFS

Depending on the TFS version you use, it might be necessary to have a compatibility pack installed (for TFS2010 and TFS2012).

TFS2010: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10834

TFS2012: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29983

An overview of exactly which set of [Service Packs and Compatibility packs to install for each combination of TFS, Visual Studio and Windows can be found in this blog post](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html).

Comment: i have installed TFS Explorer as you described. Now i can see it on the menu under Tools. Now i am installing TFS 2012 on an other machine. After that i will test TFS Explerer from VS2008 to connect to TFS 2012. If it works then i will mark your post as answer. If not, i will comment here. By the way the SP1 and compability TFS2012 packages couldnt be installed becase the installers couldnt find any update. Maybe it is already compatible with TFS2012.

Comment: Maybe the installer checks for newer versions and the compatibility pack is for users, that already had TeamExplorer installed. Never did a new installation of VS2008.

Just ask if you got problems connecting to the TFS.

Comment: I installed TFS Explorer on VS2008 then connect to TFS 2012. But i needed to uninstall VS2008 SP1 first. I uninstalled SP1 from add/remove programms, then i installed TFS Explorer, then i installed SP1 again. After all, i could connect to TFS 2012 by VS2008. But now i have an other problem. When i try to add New Team Project in TF Explorer, VS prompt an error saying that "TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without required permission or with an older version of Team Explorer......." Now i will try to find a solution to this error. If you have any idea, please share.

Comment: There are some features that are not available through "old" clients (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/03/05/permission-error-with-creating-a-team-project-from-vs-2010-on-tfs-11-beta.aspx). But you can install a TeamExplorer2012 parallel to your VS2008.

Comment: i have found this link for downloading TeamExplorer2012: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656 But it doesnt support Windows XP. As i use Windows XP SP3, i can not instal TeamExplorer2012. Now i am thinking of installing TeamExplorer2010 which supports XP. This is the link i am downloading the iso file:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329 . Can i add New Team Projects To TFS 2012 by using TeamExplorer2010? What do you think?

Comment: No, this was also answered in my link. It is only possible in TeamExplorer2012. Can't you install TeamExplorer on the machine where TFS is installed? You will need it only for some administration tasks.

Comment: You are right. i had to install TeamExplorer2012 on my TFS machine which is running Windows 7. I created the neccessary projects there then continued working in VS2008 with check-ins check-outs. As a summary, i have now a development machine which is running XP, VS2008 and TeamExplorer2008 with forward compability patch. And i have TFS 2012 on an other machine running Windows 7 and on the same machine i have TeamExplorer2012 to create Team projects only. You really helped alot. Thank you.

Comment: For XP, install Team Explorer 2010, Visual Studio 2010 SP1, Visual Studio Forward Compatibility GDR. See also: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html