# Questions on Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

In the past, we use Visual SourceSafe to do the version control of our source codes in Visual Studio 6.0. Now we used Visual Studio 2008 and it seems MS uses Team Foundation Server to replace the original Visual SourceSafe. Now I have the following questions regarding the Team Foundation Server:

1. I have Visual Studio subscription. I download a Visual Studio 2008 Team System(Team Suite). However, it seems that the DVD will only install the client. To install Team Foundation Server, I need to download another DVD called Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server, is that correct?
2. I think Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server will be compatible with Visual Studio 2008 Team System(Team Suite), is that correct? I check the Wikipedia on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server , but all it said is about Visual Studio 2010 and later versions.
3. There are two different versions of Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server, called “Workgroup Edition” and “Standard Edition”. What is the difference between them? I cannot find any official document on that.
4. Is there an official document on how to install Team Foundation Server and use it? I check https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/ , but find most of the quick start guides are just on VSTS, the cloud-based system. And I cannot find step-by-step installation and use guide on Team Foundation Server at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Do not** install a 10 year old version of TFS. Every single component is long out of support and is no longer receiving updates of any kind. In general, you're going to have trouble finding information on TFS 2008 because there have been *six* major releases since then and it's massively evolved over those six releases.

Install a modern version of TFS. You can integrate source control into Visual Studio 2008 via [MSSCCI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M).

Comment: Can Visual Studio 2008 work with TFS 2010 without installing MSSCCI? I notice that the rating for MSSCCI is very bad. Also it said "enables integrated use of Team Foundation Version Control with products that do not support Team Explorer integration", but VS2008 seems have Team Explorer already? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941875/how-to-open-team-explorer-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: I try to search TFS 2010 on my Visual Studio Subscription download. And find this: Team Foundation Server 2010 and Project Server Integration Feature Pack. What is the usage of this?

Answer (score 1):

Answer your question first:

1. Yes.
2. Technically, yes. But TFS 2008 is long out of support as Daniel mentioned.
3. Workgroup Edition is similar to Express edition in modern TFS. You could get explanation on [this website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2006/03/28/licensing-differences-between-tfs-workgroup-edition-and-tfs-standard-edition/):

> TFS Workgroup Edition is not licensed on a Server/CAL model. This
>   means CALs are not required when using the Workgroup Edition. For this
>   reason, the Workgroup Edition does not include any CALs. TFS Workgroup
>   Edition can be used by 5 unique users using any client (MSSCCI, 3rd
>   party client, VS Pro, Team Edition, Project, Excel, etc.).
>
> Once you grow beyond 5 users, you’ll need to upgrade to TFS Standard
>   Edition, which is licensed on a server/CAL model. This means that you
>   must make sure all users have the necessary CALs in place.

4. Installation guide can be downloade from the following link:
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=15743&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True

> It's not recommended to use a product that is no longer support. You
>   could use [VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/what-is-vsts) with MSSCCI provider. VSTS is a cloud service for
>   collaborating on code development, you don't need to set up a server.